# how to convert fileurl(swift) to encoded utf8 hex?

Tags: swift, bash, hex

i just want to convert  fileURLWithPath to utf8 hex format  as like bellow swift code .

```
import Cocoa
// this swift file name is aaa.swift
let arguments = CommandLine.arguments
let str = "\(arguments)"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: str)
print(url)
```

and i send bash path variable to aaa.swift file . like below
path="/Volumes/aaa/ccc.mov"

```
swift aaa.swift $path
```

then print out on terminal like below

```
%5B%22./aaa.swift%22,%20%22/Volumes/aaa/ccc.mov%22%5D -- file:///Volumes/aaa/
```

i want to get  "/Volumes/aaa/ccc.mov" this part .. 
how to do this ??

Comment: So your intended output is "/Volumes/aaa/ccc.mov"? Then why do you ask for "encoded utf8 hex" (whatever that should be)?

Comment: print `url.path` or something like that?